# get the data is greater than is equal todays date

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to fetch all data from today's date(or greater than is equal today's date). But it shows all the date before and after todays date.
See below images:
[image]

My fetch query is : 
      `SELECT * FROM tbl_reservation_info WHERE ri_id !='' AND status = 'Success'  AND  ri_arrival_date > '08-Apr-2019'`

Comment: Try this:
SELECT * FROM tbl_reservation_info WHERE ri_id !='' AND status = 'Success'  AND  DATE(ri_arrival_date) >= DATE('08-Apr-2019')

Comment: If your column is set to VARCHAR, then you are probably comparing strings and not date. Please convert your column to type date in MySQL if its not

Comment: Your column is not of DATE type. You need to format it as date for the comparison to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dates are not in a valid MySQL date format (the column is presumably a `VARCHAR` or similar), and are being compared as strings. Since all your dates start with `1`, `2`, or `3`, they are all greater than (using a string comparison) a date string starting with `0`. You need to convert the formats to compare correctly:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_reservation_info
WHERE ri_id !='' 
  AND status = 'Success' 
  AND STR_TO_DATE(ri_arrival_date, '%d-%b-%Y') > STR_TO_DATE('08-Apr-2019', '%d-%b-%Y')
```

Comment: got the point and thanks @nick its works properly. Actually, my date field type is `varchar`

Answer (score 0):

Normally a Date is saved in following format : YYYY-MM-DD
Perhaps your php-myadmin format it in this way or

you should change it from varchar/text to date otherwise sorting and filtering will be complicated. Also your code should use this format - for displaying you need to convert it.

In your screenshot the 12 is greater then the 8 you filtering.

12-Mar-2019 > 8*

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-type-overview.html

https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try [**`CURDATE()`**](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-curdate-function.php):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_reservation_info 
WHERE ri_id !='' AND status = 'Success' AND  ri_arrival_date > CURDATE();
```

With this, it skips today's date. if you want them to the add `>=`

Make sure `ri_arrival_date` is `date` format.